¿Cómo puedo crear y utilizar un DTO en Spring Boot para obtener un JSON que muestre información de libros y autores?
Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo dos tablas hechas en spring boot, libros y autores y estoy intentando obtener un json en el cual pueda mostrar la información tanto de libros como de autores. He intentado varias formas de hacerlo pero no logro dar con los resultados, por lo cual estuve investigando y encontré que puedo utilizar un DTO para crear un objeto y así poder obtener los datos que necesito pero cuando intento hacer la petición en postman me arroja un error.
Este es el codigo de mi DTO
public class BooksAuthorsDTO {

    private Long bookId;
    
    private String title;
    
    private String description;
    
    private Long authorId;
    
    private String name;
    
    public BooksAuthorsDTO(Long bookId, String title, String description, Long authorId, String name) {
        this.bookId = bookId;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.authorId = authorId;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getBookId() {
        return bookId;
    }

    public void setBookId(Long bookId) {
        this.bookId = bookId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Long getAuthorId() {
        return authorId;
    }

    public void setAuthorId(Long authorId) {
        this.authorId = authorId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    
}

Y acá está el codigo de mi repositorio, mi servicio y mi controlador
@Repository
public interface IBook extends JpaRepository<Book, Long>{
    @Query(value = "SELECT b.id AS bookId, b.title, b.description, a.id AS authorId, a.name FROM books b INNER JOIN authors a WHERE a.id = :id_author", nativeQuery = true)
    List<BooksAuthorsDTO> getBooksByAuthors(@Param("id_author") Long id_author);
}

@Service
public class BookService {
    @Autowired
    private IBook bookRepository;

    @Autowired
    private IAuthor authorRepository;

    public List<Book> getAll() {
        return bookRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<Book> findBookById(Long id) {
        return bookRepository.findById(id);
    }
    
    public List<BooksAuthorsDTO> getBooksByAuthors(Long authorId) {
        return bookRepository.getBooksByAuthors(authorId);
    }

    public Book createBook(Long authorId, Book book) {
        final Author author = authorRepository.getAuthorById(authorId);

        book.setAuthor(author);

        return bookRepository.save(book);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("Books")
public class BooksController {
    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Book> getAll() {
        return bookService.getAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Optional<Book> getById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return bookService.findBookById(id);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/getByAuthors/{authorId}")
    public List<BooksAuthorsDTO> getBooksByAuthor(@PathVariable Long authorId) {
        return bookService.getBooksByAuthors(authorId);
    }

    @PostMapping("/{authorId}")
    public Book create(@PathVariable Long authorId, @RequestBody Book book) {
        return bookService.createBook(authorId, book);
    }
}

Acá dejare el error que me arroja cuando hago la petición

org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
converter found capable of converting from type
[org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap]
to type [com.relations.relationstest.dtos.BooksAuthorsDTO]

Espero puedan ayudarme y de antemano, gracias.

Hola, me parece que tu tabla book debe tener una relación de uno a muchos con Author y al llamar la lista de books deseas traes a los author, eso es lo que deseas hacer? otra cosa con que version de java trabajas?

@PedroÁvila la versión de java que estoy utilizando es la 17, y si, tengo una relación de uno a muchos entre autores y libros en los modelos, me gustaría poder traer los datos tanto de autores como de libros y poder construir de ser posible un json mas personalizado con esos datos.

La relación que tienes es uno a muchos entre Author y Book tus entidades quedan configuradas de esta manera.
Estoy usando la dependencia Lombok pero eso no modifica la implementación con la manera que has creado tus properties.
Author


@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    private List<Book> books;

}

Book

@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;

}

Te recomiendo que uses record estan disponibles desde el jdk 14 para implementar tus DTO, tengo implementado los siguientes dtos
public record CreateAuthorResult(Long id, String name) {

}
public record CreateAuthorCommand(String name) {

}

public record GetAuthorResult(List<AuthorDto> authors) {

}

public record AuthorDto(Long id, String name, List<BookDto> books) {

}

Service
@Service
public class AuthorServiceImpl implements AuthorService {

    private final AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    public AuthorServiceImpl(AuthorRepository authorRepository) {
        this.authorRepository = authorRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public GetAuthorResult getAll() {
        List<AuthorDto> authorDTOs = authorRepository.findAll().stream()
                .map(author -> new AuthorDto(
                        author.getId(),
                        author.getName(),
                        author.getBooks().stream()
                                .map(book -> new BookDto(book.getId(), book.getTitle(), book.getDescription()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new GetAuthorResult(authorDTOs);
    }

    @Override
    public CreateAuthorResult create(CreateAuthorCommand command) {

        var author = new Author();
        boolean existsName = authorRepository.existsByName(command.name());
        if (existsName)
            throw new RuntimeException("Name exists");

        author.setName(command.name());

        authorRepository.save(author);

        return new CreateAuthorResult(author.getId(), author.getName());
    }
}

Controller
@Controller
@RequestMapping("authors")
public class AuthorController {

    private final AuthorService authorService;

    public AuthorController(AuthorService authorService) {
        this.authorService = authorService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<GetAuthorResult> getAll() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authorService.getAll());
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<CreateAuthorResult> create(@RequestBody CreateAuthorCommand dto) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(authorService.create(dto));
    }
}

Dtos de Book
public record CreateBookResult(Long id, String title, String description, Long authorId) {

}
public record CreateBookCommand(String title, String description, Long authorId) {

}

Implementación de Service de Book
@Service
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {

    private final BookRepository bookRepository;
    private final AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    public BookServiceImpl(BookRepository bookRepository, AuthorRepository authorRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
        this.authorRepository = authorRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public CreateBookResult create(CreateBookCommand command) {
        var book = new Book();
        boolean existsTitle = bookRepository.existsByTitle(command.title());
        if (existsTitle)
            throw new RuntimeException("Title exists");

        var author = authorRepository.findById(command.authorId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Author not found"));

        book.setTitle(command.title());
        book.setDescription(command.description());
        book.setAuthor(author);

        bookRepository.save(book);

        return new CreateBookResult(book.getId(), book.getTitle(), book.getDescription(), book.getAuthor().getId());
    }
}

Crear Author desde postman
 {
   "name": "George R.R. Martin"
 }

Crear Book desde postman
{
  "title": "And Then There Were None",
  "description": "And Then There Were None",
  "authorId": 3
}

Al ejecutar el endpoint de Author acción getAll te da el siguiente resultado:

Agrego el repositorio para que te sirva de guía https://github.com/PedroAvila/library
Si la respuesta te ha sido útil, dale un punto. Si ha resuelto tu problema, márcala como aceptada. Esto ayudará a otras personas que tengan el mismo problema que tú. ¡Gracias!

Muchas gracias, fue de mucha ayuda esta respuesta, seguiré indagando un poco mas.
